# Save one frame in After Effects as svg (vector) instead of psd?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, export, adobe-after-effects

I have used the 'Composition - Save Frame as - Photoshop Layers....", but was wondering if there is some plugin or some 'thing' that could save the frame as a vector file instead (.svg, .eps, .ai)?

What I am trying to do is take a character made in illustrator, pose it in AfterEffects (Using DUIK), then export the pose back as a vector file (ideally .ai). Perhaps what I REALLY need is some sort of way to puppeteer right inside illustrator!

I have seen a tool called body-movin, but its focus seems to be exporting animations as some json file then having the browser 'render' it as svg on the screen.

Comment: There's a Puppet Warp tool in Illustrator CC 2018 and later. You might want to take a look at [some tutorials](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=illustrator+puppet+warp&FORM=HDRSC3)

Comment: If you can get a frame exported as PSD, you very likely can vectorize the layers . Only have some easily removable aiming markers to place the results properly into the same AI drawing. To keep the file small you probably can delete the invisible parts in Photoshop before copying and pasting the layers to AI. I admit that's much work if you have complex shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bodymovin is an AE plugin
In the Bodymovin panel, click on preview. It will output an svg for that first frame for you.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize it had that option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the take screenshot button in bodymovin as a svg.

Comment: Could you expand on this answer?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to [edit] your answer with a bit more information. As it stands now, someone unfamiliar with Bodymovin will have a hard time understanding what you mean. Feel free to browse the site, leave more answers, upvote quality content and maybe ask a question of your own.